# std::streampos, std::streamoff and std::streamsize to long long int?

Tags: c++, file, c++11, stream, standards-compliance

To measure position/offsets/size of streams, the standard specify `std::streampos`, `std::streamoff` and `std::streamsize`, but they are implementation defined.

How to convert these types to `long long int` in a secure and portable way ? (for example to measure a file size and inject it in a function that take a long long int as argument)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, as far as C++98/03 is concerned, there *is no* `long long int`. So I'll assume you're asking about C++11.

The `streamsize` and `streamoff` are required to be typedefs of an integral type ([`streampos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/fpos) is not an integer, so you won't be passing that to anything that takes a `long long`). Since integral types are basic types, they can only be defined by either C++ or as a compiler-specific definition.

Thus, the only question is this: are these typedefs *larger* than `long long`? All integral types are convertible to a larger or equal-sized type (signed/unsigned notwithstanding, but all of the types here are signed, so no problem). But if it is larger... what are you going to do about it?

Assuming you can't change the signature of the function you are "injecting" it into (because if you could, there's no reason not to just take `streamsize` as the parameter type and thus avoid the problem), you don't have any options. You have a data value that is larger than what the function takes. There's no way of getting around it here.

You can perform a static_cast into a `long long` to shut the compiler up, but this won't help if the actual size can't fit in a `long long`.

Ultimately, this is an intractable problem. You have a function that takes a parameter which is potentially too small for what you're passing. The most you can do is detect when it might be a problem via a `static_assert`. Something like this:

```
static_assert(sizeof(std::streamsize) <= sizeof(long long), "Oops.");
```

To be honest, I wouldn't worry about it. Odds are good that `long long` will be the largest integral size that your compiler natively supports.

Comment: Apart from the case of exabytes file size, can a problem occur during the conversion to long long int ?

Comment: @Vincent: No. Integer types can be converted to a larger (or equal-sized) integer type without problem.

Comment: `streampos` implicitly converts to `streamoff`, so you might pass it to something expecting a `long long`. The difference between `streampos` and `streamoff` is support for stateful character encodings.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the value to whatever function needs a long long. `std::streamoff` and `std::streamsize` are both signed integral types, and `std::streampos` is implicitly convertible to `std::streamoff`.

edit: I suppose an assert that streamsize/streamoff is not bigger than `long long` won't hurt, in case someone comes up with __int128 file sizes.

Comment: Seems to be implementation specific, in MINGW-64 / g++ std::streampos is an adapter of std::streamoff, which is a integral type, signed 64-bit integer.

Comment: @SamGinrich that's what I described, no?

Answer (score -1):

Short response for MINGW-64: `std::streampos` has a conversion operator to 64-bit-signed-integer type `std::streamoff` as

```
std::streampos pos = ...;
std::streamoff ofs = (std::streamoff) pos;
```

So, e.g. to find the length of a file you do not need to do more than opening an `std::ifstream` and evaluate ...

```
static unsigned long long getStreamSize(std::ifstream& is)
{
    std::streampos savePos = is.tellg();
    is.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::streampos endPos = is.tellg();
    is.seekg(savePos);
    return (std::streampos)endPos;
}
```

... or think STL was another island ...

Comment: Where in the C++ standard does it specify that `tellg()` returns an integer type that represents a count of bytes from the start of a file?  And `is.seekg(0, std::ios::end)` is undefined behavior for a binary stream: "The restrictions on reading and writing a sequence controlled by an object of class `basic_filebuf<charT, traits>` are the same as for reading and writing with the Standard C library FILEs."  See https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268

Comment: No idea, where you go with your question.
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/
Specifications are specifications and use case are use cases
and this time disjoint.

Comment: cplusplus.com is not only no reference, it's actually not very accurate. Just because cplusplus.com says something doesn't make it true.  [**What's wrong with cplusplus.com?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520052/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com)

Comment: :) We understand, that "the standard" design does not foresee someone asking for a file size as an integer and insofar is useless.

Comment: If that was meant to be a standard way to get a file size, riddle me this, Batman:  Why did C++17 add `std::filesystem::file_size`?  Umm, because it wasn't there before... And I guess you're not aware that once you ask for a file size, it's not longer relevant and using it is a [TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use)  waiting to happen?  I code to higher standards then TOCTOU bugs and explicit undefined behavior per the language specification

Comment: And you've also fallen into the trap that just because something related to a file is an  integer value that it must be the file size.

Comment: Some Upper Cloud Cuckoo Home has no file size.

Comment: finally there is a horizon of hope: we see in C++ 2020, there is a contains-relation for std::set<> ;)