# Do I need to include <cstring> and <stdlib.h> for c_str(), atoi and atof functions?

Tags: c++, cstring, atoi, atof, c-str

I'm using `c_str()`, `atoi` and `atof` functions for converting string variables to integer or float/double. 
For example,

```
val = atoi(val1.c_str());   
val = atof(val1.c_str());
```

So, I would like to know if I need to include  and .
Thanks.

Comment: `atoi` and friends are in `stdlib.h`. `c_str()` is a member function of `std::string`, which is in the `string` header. You can get that information yourself by searching here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/

Comment: There are two possibilities: Try to included the suspects until the compiler warning changes or read the descriptions as juanchopanza referred.

Comment: Downvoters gonna downvote.

Comment: @harper Your first suggestion is not great because you can end up with a non-portable solution (e.g. by including a header that includes one of the headers you actually need.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks about a C++ reference. Finding out in which header a function lives can be easily done with a minimal research effort. Moreover, it doesn't add value to Stackoverflow.

Comment: You should avoid `atoi` and friends, because they will give you the same result (0) for the two strings `"0"` and `"xxx"`, which makes error handling almost impossible.

Answer (score 2):

None of those require the header `<cstring>`. The function `c_str()` requires `<string>` and including `<cstdlib>` (the C++ version of the `<stdlib.h>` header) guarantees you have `std::atoi` and `std::atof`.

Also, the site cplusplus.com is not necessarily the best reference, you should probably use [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Comment: Almost: `atoi` and `atof` are not guaranteed to be in `cstdlib`. What is guaranteed is that you get `std::atoi` and `std::atof`. Both `atoi` and `atof` are guaranteed to be in `stdlib.h`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Both? Surely you mean just the non-`std` versions.

Comment: @JosephMansfield I meant both `atoi` and `atof`. Edited the comment.

Comment: Is there a special reason to choose [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com) over [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com)?

Comment: Here is a discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520052/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com

cppreference.com is also a wiki

Comment: per [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) and a test on a MAC <cstring> is the correct include.