# Mixing "untyped" operator new and "typed" delete

Tags: c++

I want to make a class factory that can create classes knowing nothing about them (eg no headers included). I created a factory class with map, that stores info about classes (sizeof and pointer to static method) by strings ( map(string, mystruct) ), which is filled from each class.

When factory is producing a class, it allocates raw memory and calls static method, which then calls the default constructor on that memory:

```
void *ptr = operator new(classSize);
classCCaller(ptr);//void (*classCCaller)(void*)
```

then inside the static method of that class the following code is executed:

```
new (ptr) SomeClassConstructor();
```

The produced class is then put in some container.

Question - is it ok to delete classes, created that way, by

```
delete p;//SomeClass *p;
```

or should I manually call destructor and use operator delete on untyped pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have to say `p->~SomeClass(); operator delete(ptr);`, where `p = static_cast<SomeClass*>(ptr)`.

Comment: Does that mean that lines 29 and 35 in the example at [CPlusPlus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) are not correct?

Comment: @SeriousAlexej Line 35 is undefined, since the object has never been constructed. That site should be taken with large grains of salt.

Comment: @SeriousAlexej: [shock horror](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520052/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com) :-)