# Understanding exception safety of shared_ptr::void reset (U* p);

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm trying to understand the exception safety of the `template <class U> void shared_ptr::reset (U* p);` function. [In the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/reset/) I found this:

> Additionally, a call to this function has the same side effects as if
>   shared_ptr's destructor was called before its value changed (including
>   the deletion of the managed object if this shared_ptr was unique).

So, we can assume that destructor doesn't throw. But what if the `operator new` throws? What state of the `shared_ptr` will we have then? Does it remain unchanged?

Comment: [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset) is a little more descriptive: " std::bad_alloc if required additional memory could not be obtained. May throw implementation-defined exception for other errors. delete ptr is called if an exception occurs."

Comment: Which `operator new`? The one called to allocate the new control block?

Comment: As a small sidenote preferr http://cppreference.com over cplusplus.com. [Cplusplus.com has many small mistakes and some bad examples.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520052/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [util.smartptr.shared.mod], all four overloads of `shared_ptr::reset(stuff)` are exactly equivalent to

```
shared_ptr(stuff).swap(*this)
```

If constructing `shared_ptr(stuff)` throws (e.g., if allocating the new control block (or whatever equivalent mechanism used by the implementation) throws), then `*this` is unaffected because you never get to the `swap`, and any pointer passed in `stuff` is deleted appropriately (because that's guaranteed by `shared_ptr`'s constructor).

`swap` itself is nothrow, and so is destroying the temporary `shared_ptr` after the swap.

Comment: Great answer. I might add that the destructor for `stuff` must also be `noexcept`

Comment: @AndyG That's required by the corresponding constructor's spec, on pain of UB.

Answer (score 1):

The function takes a pointer. That means the new would have to be done prior to execution entering the function. Inside the function I assume only a pointer and some of integer type are being assigned and those don't throw.

Comment: Shared pointer should allocate internal storage (with counter).