# Why the function returns boolean when it's declared int?

Tags: c++, function, return-value

I'm learning C++ with previous Java experience.I found the following example in the cplusplus.com :

```
int CDummy::isitme (CDummy& param)
{
  if (&param == this)
  { 
       return true; //ampersand sign on left side??
  }
  else 
  {    
       return false;
  }
}
```

My question is : Why does it return boolean `false` when I clearly declared the method as `int` ? It's never possible in Java.
The link of the example is : [here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/classes2/)

Comment: Are you asking why it's legal (that's because there's an implicit conversion from `bool` to `int`), or are you asking why the code is written that way (that can only be answered by the author)? Can you link to the source? As a matter of style, and with insufficient context to be sure, it should **probably** be defined to return `bool`.

Comment: @KeithThompson - The author is writing crap code IMHO

Comment: I'm asking why it's legal.Is it even possible?As as person from Java, I see it as wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't trust an example that takes so long to say `return &param == this;`.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/classes2/

Comment: Please add that link to the question.

Comment: Perhaps historical reasons? Very early versions of C++, and versions of C prior to C99, didn't have a `bool` type, so `int` was commonly used to represent boolean values (`0` for false, anything else (especially `1`) for true). That's no excuse for writing code like that for a C++ reference site.

Comment: @SittingBull cplusplus.com is a well known source for notoriously bad samples and wrong reference statements. I'd urgently recommend you switch to en.cppreference.com when looking for reference.

Comment: I've submitted a comment on that example. (Of course that won't help the other examples on the site, and I don't have time to do more.)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Now I'm really afraid.I have been learning from this site.

Comment: @SittingBull I can feel with you. There are much better and reliable resources available than cplusplus.com actually.

Comment: @SittingBull You might be interested in reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520052/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the question of why the function does what it does is best answered by the author of the function, it is easy to explain why C++ allows such function to compile without a problem.

In C++ `bool` is [*a fundamental integral type*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_integral/), so it can be freely converted to a number: `true` becomes `1`, and `false` becomes zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an instance of implicit conversion. In c++, `1` and `true` (also `0` and `false`) are the same thing(s).

You could also do something like

```
while (1)
   //Infinite loop
```

or

```
bool b = false;
if (b == 0) {
    //This is reached
}
else {
    //This is not
}
```

Comment: (Java is a bit less messy here, but the second example would afaik also work.)

Comment: It is even the case [that all numbers other than 0 are truthy](https://www.cprogramming.com/reference/truth.html)