# Does std::ofstream truncate or append by default?

Tags: c++, fstream

If you call the `std::ofstream` constructor without `openmode` flags, the [default flag is `ios_base::out`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/). But does this imply `ios_base::trunc` or `ios_base::app`?

In other words, if you already have a non-empty file "past.txt" in your file system and you call

```
std::ofstream stream( "past.txt" );
stream << "new content";
```

will "new content" be appended to the prior contents of "past.txt" or will it replace the prior contents?

Comment: I have a feeling this question is based on wrong choice of the reference. [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) should be better.

Comment: `ios_base::out` is the same as `ios_base::out |  ios_base::trunc`.   I can't find a good reference link, but a google search hit on a couple of [text books](https://books.google.com/books?id=eC-iLe_iET8C&pg=PA1124&dq=Same+as+ios_base::out+%7C+ios_base::trunc.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip8ZfRquzOAhVCGB4KHSJuD84Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Same%20as%20ios_base%3A%3Aout%20%7C%20ios_base%3A%3Atrunc.&f=false),

Comment: As per LogicStuff's link, the ofstream ctor default is `out` which behaves the same in `basic_filebuf::open` as `out|trunc`, and therefore truncates.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer can be easily found from the right reference material available. (Just testing out yourself will proof)

Comment: Sounds like this might be another case of [what's wrong with cplusplus.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520052/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com), though this time it's just an omission...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### The short version

It truncates by default.

---

### The medium version

The standard is basically spaghetti on this, but it eventually boils down to saying that it's the equivalent of saying `fopen(const char*, "w")` (27.9.1.4 [filebuf.members]), which then points us towards the ISO C 7.9 standard.

Checking that out provides us with §7.19.5.3, "The fopen function", which specifies the behavior when "w" is passed:

> w truncate to zero length or create text file for writing

---

### The long version

If you'd like to follow the spaghetti trail yourself, start with 27.9.1.11 [ofstream.cons], which describes the constructor's behavior as

> Effects: Constructs an object of `class basic_ofstream<charT,traits>`, initializing the base class with
>   `basic_ostream(&sb`) and initializing `sb` with `basic_filebuf<charT,traits>())` (27.7.3.2, 27.9.1.2),
>   then calls `rdbuf()->open(s, mode|ios_base::out)`. If that function returns a null pointer, calls
>   `setstate(failbit)`.

Where `rdbuf()` returns `basic_filebuf<charT,traits>*` (27.9.1.13 [ofstream])

Which leads us to 27.9.1.1 [filebuf], or more specifically, 27.9.1.4 [filebuf.members] , which describes the `open` function:

```
basic_filebuf<charT,traits>* open(const char* s, ios_base::openmode mode);
```

as

> Effects: If `is_open() != false`, returns a null pointer. Otherwise, initializes the filebuf as required.
>   It then opens a file, if possible, whose name is the NTBS `s` (as if by calling `std::fopen(s,modstr)`).
>   The NTBS `modstr` is determined from `mode & ~ios_base::ate` as indicated in Table 132. If mode is
>   not some combination of flags shown in the table then the open fails.

NTBS: Null-terminated byte-string

Table 132 describes equivalence rules between C++ `ios_base::openmode` and C-style stdio strings:

> ```
> Table 132 — File open modes
> |
> |   'ios_base' flag combination   | 'stdio' equivalent |
> | binary | in | out | trunc | app |                    |
> |        |    |  +  |       |     |        "w"         |
> |                     etc...                           |
> ```

Which leads us to a footnote on the same page that states:

> ...the function signatures `fopen(const char*, const char*)` and `fseek(FILE*, long,
>   int)` are declared, in `<cstdio>` (27.9.2).

Which sends us, predictably, to 27.9.2 [c.files], which provides the nearly useless Table 134, but then references the C standard:

> See also: ISO C 7.9, Amendment 1 4.6.2.

Which I talk about in the main portion of this answer.

Comment: So what's the answer?

Comment: @A.Smoliak The answer to the question "Does std::ofstream truncate or append by default?" is "Truncate"