# How value of map is getting initialized as there is no assignment operator used?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    map<int, int> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        m[i]++;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout<<m[i];
}
```

Output:

11111

Now, how come value of m[i] is getting initialized? Shouldn't it translate to m[i]'s value incremented by 1?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098080/stdmapoperator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Shouldn't it translate to m[i]'s value incremented by 1?

It is.  when you do `map[key]` if `key` does not exist it adds it to the map and value initializes the value that is mapped to key.  For an `int` value initialization means zero initialization.  So, `m[i]` is `0`, and the the `++` increments it to `1`.

Answer (score 3):

If you looks at [the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) for `std::map::operator[]`

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, **performing an insertion if such key does not already exist**.

So basically `m[i]` will perform an insertion if that key does not already exist, then the increment will occur with a reference to the newly inserted value.