# c++ std::find specify starting position

Tags: c++

Is it possible to specify the starting position for the string being searched with `std::find`?

something like

```
std::string str = "kjsdfsdxksldfjsldjf";
int position = str.find("x", 2);
```

So it will start searching from index `2`? I have a recursive function and need to specify the next starting pos (I'm not interested in searching every occurrence of the character with while/for loop)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Comment: Yes, the [second overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) here does exactly that. Does your code not work? What's your question exactly?

Comment: Thank you @bolov and ami

Comment: One question did you try your code as it's perfectly fine?

Comment: std::string::find() doesn't return an int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes according to this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find
second argument is position of the first character in the string to be considered in the search.

Comment: Rather use en.cppreference.com cplusplus.com is an unreliable and buggy resource.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ just curious but can you point me to a bug on cplusplus?

Comment: @Logman I don't have one at hand now, but seen bugs several times. Especially in their examples.

Comment: @Logman See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520052/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com) for examples.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes some examples there are "not good quality" ;). But actually I never found any bug in reference. I used them before cppreference. Anyway good to know.