# I'm having a hard time understanding the c++ .find function

Tags: c++

I'm really new to coding. In my program, I'm trying to assign proper prefixes to countries. For example: putting in "Philippines" gives out "les Philippines".

Anyway, I'm trying to find if a country is in my "plain" list of exceptions of countries that don't need a prefix. So if you put in "israel" you only get "Israel"

```
string country;
string prefix;
string plain = "Isreal, Madagascar, Sri Lanka, Singapore, Monaco, Cuba, Cyprus";
string masculine = "Belize, Camboge, Mexique, Mozambique, Costa Rica, Zimbabwe, Honduras";
```

I'm assuming I need something like this:

```
if (plain.find(country))
    {
        prefix = "";
    }
```

but it's not working? Can someone explain how it works? I could do a long if statement, but I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: `if (plain.find(country) != std::string::npos)`

Comment: You'd be better off storing this list in a `std::unordered_set` and searching that.  `std::unordered_set plain { "Israel", "Madagascar" /* , etc... */ }; if (plain.contains(country)) ...` (C++20) or simply `if (plain.find(country) != plain.end()) ...`

Comment: It's better to use some sort of container than storing strings as a subset of another string, but someone who's brand new shouldn't be worried about `std::unordered_set` vs `std::vector`.

Comment: @paddy why unordered instead of a normal set?

Comment: @M.M std::unordered_set is more effective than std::set. The disadvantage is that it is ... not ordered. In general you can replace any std::unordered_set by std::set and the functionality will be the same (but obviously you cannot replace it the opposite way); still you may need to provide different custom operator< vs. operator==&&hash.

Comment: @M.M it's a habit born from personal preference, and usually because when I'm using such structures for lookups I tend to be chasing performance.  If I don't require the data to be ordered, I use `unordered_set`.  If I require ordering, I use `set`.  But sure, `set` would work just fine too.  I maintain that either of these is preferable to searching stuff in a freeform string.  Consider partial string matches like `Niger` matching `Nigeria` or `Dominica` matching `Dominican Republic`.  Just using countries as an example here, where having a list in a single string would break.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to understand what any function is doing or if anything goes wrong with it , I'd recommend you to look for its documentation. One of the popular website for docs of cpp is [cplusplus.com](https://cplusplus.com). In your case as suggested in the comments you just  need to change your if condition to `if (plain.find(country) != std::string::npos)` because `std::string::find` returns `std::string::npos` if no matches were found.

Comment: "*One of the popular website for docs of cpp is cplusplus.com*" - actually, that site is generally considered to be [not a good site to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520052/), it is full of inaccuracies and misinformation. The *more popular* and *more accurate* site is [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com) instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didn't know that, thanks for correcting me.